# How to detect all the rectangles in an image?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

In the following image, all the rectangles are a little bit deformed due to power leakage effect. I want to detect all the rectangles and obtain the positions of the rectangles. If the number of rectangles are arbitrary (maybe unknown), how to  detect?

[image]

Is there a way to detect all rectangles with MATLAB?

Answer (score 0):

The rectangles are against a black background so the easiest way to likely do this is to consider the image as a simple 2D array with values from 0 to whatever (assuming 0 is black).

You can then write and statement that says while array value is above 0 output the array coords in x and y to a new array. Once you have done this you can then write another script to find the corners of the boxes by looking to see whether each coordinate could be equal to another coordinate if you added or subtracted 1, this would give you the number of boxes and the coordinates in each box.

Then you should be able to find the centre from there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform threshold of the image with some level. And perform `regionprops()`. Read the MATLAB help Documentation.
Also refer the MATLAB code below.

```
clc
MainImg = imread('ifVsy.jpg');
BinImg = im2bw(MainImg,graythresh(MainImg));

Objects = regionprops(BinImg,'centroid');
AllCenters = cat(1, Objects.Centroid);

imshow(MainImg);
hold on
plot(AllCenters(:,1),AllCenters(:,2),'r*');
hold off
```

[image: Result Image]

Comment: Thank Amar very much! 
regionprops() is straightforward and helpful. If I also want to obtain the corners (or edges) of each rectangle, how to detect?

Comment: After some trivial, I found the property 'BoundingBox' of regionprops() is helpful to detect the boundaries of rectangles.  Thank Amar again!